# Ubuntu 18.04: laravel/framework v6.9.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system

Tags: php, linux, laravel, ubuntu

Before someone takes this down for duplication. I've checked the other pages and they weren't helpful.

I'm trying to install a package for Laravel 6 on PHP 7.2. I've also tried PHP 7.4.

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
laravel/framework v6.9.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
```

I've installed mbstring and uncommented it in both the php.ini files for 7.2 and 7.4:

```
extension=mbstring
```

The only solution to this I would know is restarting the apache2 server. But I still get the error.

My composer.json is requiring PHP 7.2.

I'm also presented with these errors:

```
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.9.0, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.9.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a lot of required extensions. Run `php -i` on the command line to check for the existing extensions. Note that on most installations, the command-line php.ini is different from the web-based php.ini, so you need to make adjustments in both files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please run the below commands on Ubuntu OS.

1. Sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install php-mbstring

Answer (score 4):

Try to install mbstring extension.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring
```