# Failed to run composer to install laravel 7

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Hello I found a problem here in which I am unable to run the composer, and I am receiving the following error:

> Error when performing composer installation

```
Do not run Composer as root / superuser! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from the lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved for an installable set of packages.

Issue 1
- Installation request for hashids / hashids 4.0.0 -> satisfactory for hashids / hashids [4.0.0].
- hashids / hashids 4.0.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing on your system.
Issue 2
- Request for installation of laravel / framework v7.4.0 -> satisfactory for laravel / framework [v7.4.0].
- laravel / framework v7.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing on your system.
Issue 3
- Installation request for lcobucci / jwt 3.3.1 -> satisfactory by lcobucci / jwt [3.3.1].
- lcobucci / jwt 3.3.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing on your system.
Issue 4
- Request for installation of the alloy / common brand 1.3.2 -> satisfactory by the alloy / common brand [1.3.2].
- league / commonmark 1.3.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested mbstring PHP extension is missing from your system.
Issue 5
- Request for installation of the facade / ignition 2.0.2 -> satisfactory for the facade / ignition [2.0.2].
- facade / ignition 2.0.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing on your system.
Issue 6
- Request to install phpunit / phpunit 8.5.3 -> satisfactory by phpunit / phpunit [8.5.3].
- phpunit / phpunit 8.5.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing on your system.
Issue 7
- Request to install the scrivo / highlighted.php v9.18.1.1 -> satisfactory by the scrivo / highlighted.php [v9.18.1.1].
- scrivo / highlighted.php v9.18.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing on your system.
Issue 8
- laravel / framework v7.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing on your system.
- facade / flare-client-php 1.3.2 requires lighting / pipeline ^ 5.5 | ^ 6.0 | ^ 7.0 -> satisfactory by laravel / framework [v7.4.0].
- Installation request for facade / flare-client-php 1.3.2 -> satisfactory for facade / flare-client-php [1.3.2].


You can also run `php --ini` inside the terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Does anyone know how to tell me where I'm going wrong? And how can I be solving this problem?

Comment: Your system doesn't have the php extension mbstring required to install those packages

Comment: Looks like you doesn't have the mbstring extension installed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615823/ubuntu-18-04-laravel-framework-v6-9-0-requires-ext-mbstring-the-requested

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Which parts of that error message are unclear to you?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` or `sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring` should solve the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 7 requires the following php modules

- php-zip
- php-mysql
- php-mcrypt
- php-xml
- php-mbstring

use the following code to install them on fedora/centos/rhel. This will install missing modules only,

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,epel install php-zip php-mysql php-mcrypt php-xml php-mbstring

service httpd restart
```

for ubuntu/debian check the current php version installed and install modules accordingly. for example, if php 7.2 is installed, use the following code.

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.2 php7.2-mcrypt php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xmlrpc php7.2-soap php7.2-gd php7.2-xml php7.2-cli php7.2-zip php7.2-mysql

sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```